# Is stat growth related to the current job when levelling up?

Tags: tactics-ogre-psp

I googled a lot for this question but it's hard to get a final answer to this question because the PSP system seems to be very different from the original one, since on PSP class levelling is global.

As far as I understand, in the PSP version, the answer to my question is 'NO', since the only stat's increment is about base stats (+.1 to all base stats when levelling up.). So there is no difference in gaining 10 levels in the Warrior class and then switch to a level 1 Knight (for example) than gaining 10 levels in the Cleric class and then switch to a lavel 1 Knight.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently fully-completed the game including all CODA stuff and was exposed to a tonne of guides / discussions in the process. The guides of interest here are any relating to building decent Cursed Weapons - where you need to sacrifice a generic party member and have their stats affect the resulting weapon.

What I found was as you have said; all characters in all classes have a very minor boost to *all* stats when levelling up (0.1 points). To exploit this as much as possible and afford the best cursed weapon you can get, the idea is to level up one class at a time with all of your characters. This maximises the stats that your characters can earn, because they don't miss out on the earlier levels of another class.

There is some talk about it here:

- [Bonus to Base Stats From Leveling Explained!!!!!](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/999440-/58172131)
- [Perfect cursed weapon...](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/999440-tactics-ogre-let-us-cling-together/60226641)